# CRC calculation in Python (from C++ code conversion)

Tags: python, crc

I am trying to rewrite the code for calculating the CRC given in the documentation of the sensor I am trying to communicate with.

Datasheet screens:
[image]
[image]

Example message I want to send:
[image]

My Python code:

```
def calc_crc(p_buffer, buffer_size):
    poly = 0x8408
    crc = 0

    for j in range(buffer_size):
        crc = crc ^ p_buffer[j]

        for i_bits in range(8):
            carry = crc & 1
            crc = crc / 2

            if carry:
                crc = crc^poly

    return crc


# MESSAGE: IMU_GET_PROTOCOL_MODE------(0x13)
# Used to get the communication baud rate
def imu_get_protocol_mode():
    frame_sync_byte = 'FF'
    frame_start_byte = '02'
    addr = '00'
    cmd = '13'
    len_msb = '00'
    len_lsb = '00'
    data = ''
    frame_end_byte = '03'

    to_calc_crc = addr + cmd + len_msb + len_lsb + data
    to_calc_crc_b = bytearray.fromhex(to_calc_crc)

    crc = calc_crc(to_calc_crc_b, 4)

    command = frame_sync_byte + frame_start_byte + to_calc_crc + crc + frame_end_byte
    print(command)


imu_get_protocol_mode()
```

Unfortunately, I'm weak in bit operations. The script returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DANE\PyCharm Projects\INC\testy.py", line 41, in <module>
    imu_get_protocol_mode()
  File "C:\DANE\PyCharm Projects\INC\testy.py", line 35, in imu_get_protocol_mode
    crc = calc_crc(to_calc_crc_b, 4)
  File "C:\DANE\PyCharm Projects\INC\testy.py", line 11, in calc_crc
    carry = crc & 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'int'
```

I don't understand it because both "crc" and "1" are of type int

Can anyone guide me to make this CRC calculations correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of a division is by default a float. This is the reason `crc` switches its type from `int` to `float` in this statement: `crc = crc / 2`

If you want an integer division try `crc = crc // 2`.

For more details have a look [here](https://www.learndatasci.com/solutions/python-double-slash-operator-floor-division/).

Comment: Or replace it with `crc = crc >> 1`. Dividing by 2 and shifting by one to the right is the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you just add print statements you'll be able to see the moment `crc` changes to float.

```py
def calc_crc(p_buffer, buffer_size):
    poly = 0x8408
    crc = 0

    for j in range(buffer_size):
        print(f"{crc=}\n{p_buffer[j]=}")
        crc = crc ^ p_buffer[j]

        for i_bits in range(8):
            carry = crc & 1
            print(f"carry = crc & 1 => {crc=}\n{carry=}")
            crc = crc / 2
            print(f"crc = crc / 2 => {crc=}\n{carry=}")

            if carry:
                crc = crc^poly
                print(f"crc = crc^poly => {crc=}\n{carry=}")

    return crc


# MESSAGE: IMU_GET_PROTOCOL_MODE------(0x13)
# Used to get the communication baud rate
def imu_get_protocol_mode():
    frame_sync_byte = 'FF'
    frame_start_byte = '02'
    addr = '00'
    cmd = '13'
    len_msb = '00'
    len_lsb = '00'
    data = ''
    frame_end_byte = '03'

    to_calc_crc = addr + cmd + len_msb + len_lsb + data
    to_calc_crc_b = bytearray.fromhex(to_calc_crc)

    crc = calc_crc(to_calc_crc_b, 4)

    command = frame_sync_byte + frame_start_byte + to_calc_crc + crc + frame_end_byte
    print(command)


imu_get_protocol_mode()
```

```
crc=0
p_buffer[j]=0
carry = crc & 1 => crc=0
crc = crc / 2 => crc=0.0
```